# Using Alamofire with an iOS 8.0 Embedded Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, alamofire

I am trying to use Alamofire within a custom framework that I am creating. I created my custom framework project, added the Podfile, installed Alamofire. I then created a sample project to test out my custom framework.

The sample project is compiling fine with my custom framework import, that is until I started making Alamofire calls within my framework. Now Xcode is complaining about "Missing require module 'Alamofire'" within my sample project. And if I add "import Alamofire" to the swift file, Xcode now complains about "No such module 'Alamofire'"

Is if possible to use a swift framework such as Alamofire within a custom framework, and does the project using my custom framework need to import the Alamofire framework as well?

Comment: Did you open the xcworkspace or the xcproj?

Comment: I am using the xcworkspace created by Cocoapods, and added the sample test project to it.

Comment: Did you link the cocoapods library inside Link Binary With Libraries?

Comment: Did anyone get any info on this?

Comment: In the end I decided to just use Alamofire.swift as it is without importing it as a framework.

Comment: I am facing the same problem . I would like create one custom framework that has dependency on Alamofire. I included Alamofire with cocoa pods. but not able to import Alamofire in swift file. Please suggest if have any solution for the same

Comment: @user4781334 you can add third party library while creating your custom framework as follows...clean your project several times or restart your xcode if possible. I am able to solve the same problem with clean of project

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to use Alamofire within your custom framework, but you need to also include Alamofire in the podfile of your sample project (the project that uses your framework). Your podfile should look like this:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
#   pod 'MyFramework'  Include MyFramework if it is a cocoadpod
   pod 'Alamofire'
end
```

The error "Missing required module 'Alamofire'" happens because your framework doesn't actually include Alamofire when you use it in some other project, and you cannot import Alamofire in your sample project for the same reason.

If you plan to make your project a Pod you can include the following line in your `podspec`:

```
s.dependency "Alamofire", "~> 3.1.5"
```

Including Alamofire as a dependency in the podspec instructs cocoapods to also include it when your framework is installed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if this is your issue of not, but for swift stuff you have to use the `use_frameworks!` directive in your Podfile.  Could that be the issue?

I ran into this once and found answer from  https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift